# Clojure Refs in a game loop for state: why does it go slower and slower?

Tags: clojure, ref

I am trying to update a map each step based on the previous step. I have a ref that is a vector of vectors of numbers and to blur my world-map I rotate left, right, up and down and then average my four new world-maps. I do this update as an 'alter' in the main loop. It is initially fast but slows down more and more. Am I not letting go of the head in some way that I'm not aware of? It seems like it does all previous calculations each step. Here is my code:

I define the map:

```
      (def gradient-map
       (ref( vec (repeat columns (vec (repeat rows 0))))))
```

Here is my update function:

```
(defn rotate-grid-up [grid]
  (map #(concat (rest %) [(last %)]) grid))
(defn rotate-grid-down [grid]
  (map #(concat [(first %)] (drop-last %)) grid))
(defn rotate-grid-right [grid]
  (concat [(first grid)] (drop-last grid)))
(defn rotate-grid-left [grid]
  (concat (rest grid) [(last grid)]))

(defn blur [grid]
  (let [g1 (rotate-grid-up grid)
        g2 (rotate-grid-down grid)
        g3 (rotate-grid-left grid)
        g4 (rotate-grid-right grid)]
   (vec (map
     (fn [r1 r2 r3 r4 r5]
       (vec (map
        #(/ (+ %1 %2 %3 %4 %5) 5)
        r1 r2 r3 r4 r5)))
     g1 g2 g3 g4 grid))))
```

Then in my draw loop I blur each tic

```
(dosync (alter gradient-map blur))
```

and the draw loop slows to a crawl.

Comment: All of your rotate functions are lazy (both `map` and `concat` are lazy). Maybe you should try wrapping the bodies of all your rotate functions in [`doall`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doall) and see if that helps.

Comment: Are you sure that this `doasync` is the cluprit ? what else do u do in your draw loop?

Comment: Why are you using refs? Are there multiple threads? Are you creating work at a faster rate than it can be completed?

Answer (score 0):

The code creates too many vectors, leading to increasing memory use and gc.

You could try not creating vectors, doing everything lazily, or you could minimize their creation. Or, you could instead use a matrix lib (e.g. core.matrix or Incanter).

Also, unrelated, do you need a ref for the game state ? Surely an atom would be enough if there're no dependencies with other such things ?

Answer (score 0):

On my fairly new computer blur takes about 2.7 seconds for a 1000x1000 grid. Is your world-map growing over time?